# Openrowset on SQL Server 2008 R2 installed in Windows 2008 64 bit machine

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005, t-sql

I'm trying to working with Openrowset on SQL Server 2008 R2 installed in Windows 2008 64 bit machine.When I execute the below query, i got an error like below.Please help me out.

```
SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET('Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0','Excel 8.0;Database=E:\01112012.xls;','SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]')
```

ERROR:

Msg 7403, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
The OLE DB provider "Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0" has not been registered.

Comment: After I installed Microsoft Access Database Engine 2010 Redistributable, I have changed above query and it worked fine for me.Below is the modified query. 
SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET('MICROSOFT.ACE.OLEDB.12.0', 'Excel 12.0;HDR=YES;DATABASE=E:\01112012.xls',sheet1$)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you installed:  ->[Microsoft Access Database Engine 2010 Redistributable](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=13255)

- This download will install a set of components that facilitate the transfer of data between existing Microsoft Office files such as Microsoft Office Access 2010 (*.mdb and *.accdb) files and Microsoft Office Excel 2010 (*.xls, *.xlsx, and *.xlsb) files to other data sources such as Microsoft SQL Server. Connectivity to existing text files is also supported. ODBC and OLEDB drivers are installed for application developers to use in developing their applications with connectivity to Office file formats.

Comment: Yes, I do have this installed on the machine.

Comment: After I installed this, I have changed above query and it worked fine for me.Below is the modified query.    



select * from  OPENROWSET('MICROSOFT.ACE.OLEDB.12.0',
'Excel 12.0;HDR=YES;DATABASE=E:\01112012.xls',sheet1$)

Answer (score 0):

To run OPENROWSET in 64 bit version of windows.

1-  Install AccessDatabaseEngine_x64.exe (Restart is required).

2-  If you are using SQL Management Studio, run Management Studio as administrator. If you don’t run it as an administrator account you will have this error (Cannot initialize the data source object of OLE DB provider "MICROSOFT.ACE.OLEDB.12.0" for linked server "(null)".

3-  Run this command to configure your Database

```
EXEC sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1;
RECONFIGURE with override;
GO

EXEC sp_configure 'Ad Hoc Distributed Queries', 1;
RECONFIGURE with override;
GO

EXEC master . dbo. sp_MSset_oledb_prop N'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' , N'AllowInProcess' , 1
GO

EXEC master . dbo. sp_MSset_oledb_prop N'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' , N'DynamicParameters' , 1
GO
```

4-   Don’t use ‘select * from  sheet1$’ in OPENROWSET function. Try this code.

```
select * from OPENROWSET('MICROSOFT.ACE.OLEDB.12.0', 'Excel 12.0;HDR=YES;DATABASE=D:\test.xlsx', sheet1$)
```

If still you have (32 bit) error, try to restart your SQL service and check your C:\Windows\Temp and see do you have access to this directory or not.